# What is the correct way to express yearly quarters? Is using roman numerals correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context, numbers, business-language

While looking over a company's annual report, I realized that every business quarter was denoted using roman numerals. E.g. QI,2014     QII, 2014    etc.

I am sure I am being petty and pedantic, however, do you need to express the year completely or should it be: **IQ14 or 1Q14**

Also, the comma used in QI, 2014 appears jarring to my mind.

Or is it just business writing?

Comment: “QI, 2014” seems quite an odd way to write it to me too—but then I’m not much up on my business jargon. Sounds more like it’s [season L of a certain TV show](http://qi.com/television/series-l/). The only variant I’ve seen often enough to say I’m really familiar with it is _1q14_ or _1q2014_.

Comment: Although Roman numerals are generally understood to related to ordinality, *IQ* is obviously confusing and thus seldom (never?) used. AFAIK, there is no single standard followed across domains. I have seen the formats *1Q2014* & *1Q-2014* in finance-related writing. The format *QI/2014* is sometimes (very few cases) found too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a style question. However, comma would add a visual chaos.
I am not sure of the best answer. I looked up the question in the CMoS but couldn’t find the answer.

However, [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/q/quarter.asp), puts the quarter with its relevant year, as in Q1 2014 or Q1/14, which represents the first quarter of the year 2014.

Comment: I've seen it either as Q1 or 1stQ. I've never seen roman numerals used for this purpose. Mixing the meaning of letters (digits or actual letters) within a single "word" will almost always cause confusion and should be avoided.